# Are there drawbacks to running a node on a cloud provider because of the limit of unique nodes connected per-subnet?

Tags: nodes, full-node

I currently have a full node running on Digital Ocean and have come across [this old post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=41726.0) on bitcoin talk that states that

> -- Outbound Random Selection --
>
> First the code puts the addresses into a.b.c.* buckets so only one
> connection is made to each 24 bit netmasked network.

Which seems to suggest that the core client will only connect to 1 node peer per /24 subnet which makes me think that running a node on Digital Ocean (where it will share a subnet with a lot of other machines running in the same region) won't help the network as much as if I ran a node on my home network. If this is is still the case (the post is from 2011) is it generally recommended to stay away from cloud providers for running full nodes?